# MongoDB aggregation filter array of subdocuments by missing field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given the following collection:

```json
db.test.insertOne(
    {
        test: [
            {a: "1", b: "2"},
            {a: "3"}
        ]
    }
)
```

How can you filter out the second document (with the non existing field b) of the test array inside an aggregation?

The aggregation

```json
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            test: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$test",
                    cond: {
                        $ne: ["$$this.b", null]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

still returns the subdocument with the not existing field b:

```json
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "xyz"},
    "test": [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2"
      },
      {
        "a": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'd expect the following result:

```json
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "xyz"},
    "test": [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Obviously my pipeline is more complex than that, but the problem boils down to this small example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Null and missing are different types in BSON.  To test for missing, compare with the $type:

```
                    cond: {
                        $ne: [{$type:"$$this.b"}, "missing"]
                    }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cxjaZSTqX1t)

Comment: Thanks for this, this solves the problem. But how is this working then: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/
Shouldn't this logic apply everywhere?

Comment: A special case was added to the query language so that null would match nonexistent, but that appears to be the only place.

Comment: Same issue in mongoDB 4.2 , you save my day thanks